# Python MPI4PI non-blocking communication error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi4py

I am reading through the MPI4PY tutorial, and stumbled upon an error.

The tutorial code yields and error. From here: http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#point-to-point-communication

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    req = comm.isend(data, dest=1, tag=11)
    req.wait()
elif rank == 1:
    req = comm.irecv(source=0, tag=11)
    data = req.wait()
```

This code gives:

```
$ mpirun -n 8 python3 pywork/esd.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywork/esd.py", line 37, in <module>
    req = comm.irecv(source=0, tag=11)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1180, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.irecv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:95932)
TypeError: irecv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source'
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[28451,1],1]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it seems that `irecv` has no attribute source. How can i communicate with a given process in a non-blocking way?

EDIT: My version is 1.3.1, which seems to be the stable one